# Working with WorkerStateEvent without casting?

Tags: service, concurrency, event-handling, javafx-2, task

I am currently dispatching my Business Logic via the [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm) API JavaFX offers. But there is one part I stumble over which does not feel *clean* to me.

Basically if you create a Service which may look like this

```
public class FooCommand extends Service<Foo> {
    @Override protected Task<Foo> createTask() {
        return new Foo();
    }
}
```

and I set the `onSucceeded`

```
FooCommand fooCommand = CommandProvider.get(FooCommand.class);
fooCommand.setOnSucceeded(new FooSucceededHandler());
fooCommand.start();
```

to an instance of this class

```
public class FooSucceededHandler implements EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent> {
    @Override public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
        Foo f = (Foo) event.getSource().getValue();
    }   
}
```

**But as you can see I need to cast the value of the `Worker` to `(Foo)`. Is there some cleaner way to do it?**

Answer (score 0):

You could just make your own abstract class:

```
public abstract class EventCallback<T> implements EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent> {

@Override
public void handle(final WorkerStateEvent workerStateEvent) {
    T returnType = (T) workerStateEvent.getSource().valueProperty().get();
    this.handle(returnType);
}

public abstract void handle(T objectReturned);

}
```

And then using it:

```
final EventCallback<MonType> eventCallback = new EventCallback<MonType>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(final MonType objectReturned) {
            // DO STUFF
        }
};
```

As it is also an EventHandler, it is compatible with JavaFX concurrent API.

Comment: well this would just shift the problem into another layer. You cast in your abstract anyways even though you don't know if the result is this instance anyway. The problem is, that you would need to catch the type by using your "programmers skills" but not the type check of the compiler. I tried extending the WorkerStateEvent but does sadly not work, since it does not allow sub-classes (yet? I dont know about Java8)

Comment: You can't extend WorkerStateEvent without implementing a custom CommandProvider / Service / etc... as they are components that manage the construction and the dispatch of these events. So, either you wait for the JavaFX team to implement a value property which would be generic inside WorkerStateEvent (which implies modifying every part of JavaFX where this event is instanciated), either you make your own layer to manage the cast smoothly. I don't see another option :(